# solr: find last/highest unique key & range search

Tags: php, lucene, solr

i have an lucene index with an "uniqueKey"

```
<uniqueKey>ID</uniqueKey>
```

As far as i know, this key have to be "text" (not int or long).

```
<field name="ID" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

An small application used the lucene index in order to search only in those records, which are added since the last run of that application.

To reach that goal, i'm trying the following.

1. Load the last ID (from flatfile)
   into the variable $oldID
2. get the current (last/highest) ID
   from Solr/lucene into the variable
   $currentID
3. execute an range search between
   $oldID and $currentID
4. Save the $currentID into a flat file
   for next Search/for next run

Unfortunately I notice a problem:

A.) how to find the highest ID?

or B.) how i handle the unique key as an digit, not text/char

I tried something like that:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select/?defType=func&q=max(ID,0)&fq=ID:[$oldID+TO+$currentID]&fl=ID
```

...which returns strange thinks:  "999999" as the highest value. That's not correct, because the highest ID is 1043725. I think this is because ID is an Text-Field

C.) maybe there is any other way to search only at the last added recoreds?

Thanks for any kind of help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solr's uniqueKey field can support any of the data type classes that Solr supports. While the underlying Lucene index itself treats all stored/indexed data as text, Solr manages the translation to treat the indexed data according to data types.

The [string field-type restriction](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#The_Unique_Key_Field) you're referring to is if you have enabled the QueryElevationComponent in solr config.  If you have not enabled that feature, you can make your uniqueKey a long to solve your issue.

Comment: that's an really interesting information - i never heard about QueryElevationComponent before. By reading that -> http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent i have one more question to understand if it is an god idea (uncritical) to disable QueryElevationComponent. Just to understand that feature: there is no effekt, if i doesn't use it explicitly. That's an prepared solar feature, active by default, to boost special kind of results. So if i don't use that feature in my application, i can disable it without any side effects!?

Comment: Query elevation allows search results to be manipulated by directly superseding calculated/scored results with specific index entries -- think of it as an override for certain search use cases. By default, it's disabled. At any rate, if you're not using it, you can disable it without side effects.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Sorting and working with the primary key (ID) now works correct. :-)